# start a python script from a batch with arguments and wait

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, batch-file

I'm trying to start a python script with arguments from a batch and wait for his success or fail. But the following batch script does not work.

```
start /wait C:\python.exe C:\script.py arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Have you already faced this issue?

Comment: Use `start /wait` if you want a new console window, especially if you're giving it an initial title for custom console settings (persisted in `HKCU\Console\[title]`); or if you need any other option provided by `start` such as setting the working directory, process priority, or CPU affinity; or use `start /wait python.exe` if you've registered "python.exe" under `[HKCU|HKLM]\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths` to avoid adding it to `PATH`. If you don't need any of these features, then using `start /wait` is redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the cmd batch you do not need to call start /wait as it will happen directly using it without the `start /wait`.

```
C:\python.exe C:\script.py arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Comment: The arguments to python.exe should not be quoted like that. Python will try to open `"C:\script.py arg1 arg2 arg3"` as the script instead of `C:\script.py`.

Comment: thank you for your answer, it's working but without quote :)